# Adjusting the size or pixelation of a background image when it goes from 1080 px width to mobile width

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, media

I'm adding in this media query to adjust the size of an image when it goes from desktop to mobile but it's not complying. Any thoughts?

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #team {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: #444 url('../img/womencoffee.jpg') center top no-repeat fixed;
  }
}
```

When I go to view it, it is still really blowing up my image on the mobile phone version.

See site section: [nonprofit section](http://pages.iu.edu/~stepcron/sipandmelt4/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You issue revolves around supplying improper parameters to your CSS properties.

In the link provide the media query is:

```css
@media ( max-width: 768px ) {
  background-color: #999999;
  background-image: image-url( 'http://placekitten.com/g/500/768' );
}
```

This one doesn't work because `image-url()` should be `url()`.

In the code provided above you have:

```css
@media ( max-width: 768px ) {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: #444 url( 'http://placekitten.com/g/500/768' ) center top no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Here you are supplying multiple parameters to `background-image` which only takes one parameter, `url()`. I think you were looking for the `background` property which lets you set multiple background properties at once.

Changing `background-image` to `background` works. Once you make this change `background-color` becomes redundant as you're redefining it with `#444`.